# How to replace all matched array which are exist in the large 2D array using python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a big 2D array. I would like to replace specific array element by another array. To be more clear, here is an example that I would like to do in python:

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(10, 3))
print "a : \n", a
a[a<200]=0
a[a>=200]=255
print "Normalize a : \n", a
```

It gives any random output like:

```
a :
    [[119  19  16]
     [226  33 102]
     [163 188 235]
     [ 22  85 176]
     [ 25 188  85]
     [ 78 146 141]
     [229  10  37]
     [ 38  79  92]
     [142 107 213]
     [107 228 145]]
Normalize a :
    [[  0   0   0]
     [255   0   0]
     [  0   0 255]
     [  0   0   0]
     [  0   0   0]
     [  0   0   0]
     [255   0   0]
     [  0   0   0]
     [  0   0 255]
     [  0 255   0]]
```

Now, I would like to replace all `[255 0 0]` with `[255 255 255]`. It is possible to use any loop like for loop but very time consume if it is a very large array. Is there any simple why to use like `np.where` or someting else that I used to replace like all elements below 200 by using `a[a<200]=0` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, yes, you can use a similar method as you did above, with `np.all`:

**Example**:

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(10, 3))

>>> a
array([[ 10, 113,  91],
       [ 99,  63, 164],
       [ 96, 130,  35],
       [193,  38,  11],
       [193, 150, 200],
       [242, 195,  28],
       [  6, 205, 168],
       [156,  35, 242],
       [246,  84,  61],
       [111, 187,  18]])

# Use `np.where` to make your normalization
b = np.where(a >= 200, 255, 0)

>>> b
array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [255,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0]])

# Replace [255,0,0] with [255,255,255]
b[np.all(b==[255,0,0], axis=1)] = [255,255,255]

>>> b
array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [  0, 255,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0]])
```

**Explanation**:

`np.all(b==[255,0,0],axis=1)` Returns where your array matches all elements of `[255,0,0]`:

```
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False])
```

So you can index your array by that to return those vectors:

```
>>> b[np.all(b==[255,0,0],axis=1)]
array([[255,   0,   0],
       [255,   0,   0]])
```

And replace them in a similar manner as you had above.